# Use replaceAll() to replace all occurrences of characters in string

Tags: java, regex, string, jenkins, replaceall

Let's say I have this example string:

```
String text = "Data/DataFrontEnd/src/pt/data,Data/DataBackEnd/src/pt/groove";
```

And I want to get this string as a result of a replacement procedure:

```
String textreplaced =  "**/src/pt/data,**/src/pt/groove";
```

Basically, what I wanted was to replace all occurrences of characters before the /src with **/. This might be tricky and I've tried to capture groups between the comma and the /src text but it doesn't work as I was expecting.

I was using the replaceAll() method (wihtin Jenkins).

Does anyone have any idea how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html):

```
String text = "Data/DataFrontEnd/src/pt/data,Data/DataBackEnd/src/pt/groove";

System.out.println(text.replaceAll("([\\w/]+)(?=/src)", "**")); // **/src/pt/data,**/src/pt/groove
```

Comment: What if I want to get `**/pt/data,**/pt/groove` instead of `**/src/pt/data,**/src/pt/groove`? @sun

Comment: @BrunoFernandes `text.replaceAll("([\\w/]+)(?=/pt)", "**"`

Comment: I believe I solved it with positive lookbehind: `text.replaceAll("([\\w/]+)(?<=/src)", "**"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative non-regex based answer, in case anyone wants it:

```
String textreplaced = "";
String[] split = text.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    textreplaced += "**" + split[i].substring(split[i].indexOf("/src"));
    if (i != split.length - 1) {
        textreplaced += ",";
    }
}
```